# STM32 SPI bandwith evaluation procedure

Tags: stm32, spi

I'm testing the SPI capabilities of STM32H7. For this I'm using the SPI examples provided in STM32CubeH7 on 2 Nucleo-H743ZI boards. I will perhaps not keep this code in my own development, rigth now the goal is to understand how SPI is working and what bandwith I can get in the different modes (with DMA, with cache enabled or not, etc...).

I'd like to share the figures I've computed, as it doesn't seem very high. In the example, if I understood correctly, the CPU is @ 400Mhz and the SPI bus frequency @ 100MHz.

For polling mode I've measured the number of cycles of the call to function HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive.

For DMA I've measured between call to HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA and call to the transfer complete callback.

Measurements of cycles where made with SysTick clocked on internal clock. Since there is no low power usage, it should be accurate.

I've just modified ST's examples to send a buffer of 1KB.

I get around 200.000 CPU cycles in polling mode, which means around 2MB/s

And around 3MB/s in DMA mode.

Since the SPI clock runs at 100Mhz I would have expected much more, especially in DMA mode, what do you think ? Is there something wrong in my test procedure ?

Comment: IMO the procedure is rubbish. Send a really large buffer - lets say 500k and then see what the speed is. Using this HAL bloatware and sending the 1k data you will not get any valuable information. You should also use the bare register approach if you try to figure out what the SPI speed is.

Comment: Additionally, "speed" is a bit meaningless without context. You could just read the datasheet for max SPI clock speed, which will match the signals on the wire. To actually be used for some purpose, you'll probably implement a sort of protocol on top of it. There's also the process of producing/consuming data, which might take significantly more time than transferring on the wire.

Comment: @P__J__ what does not using HAL help if they're going to use HAL in their product? If you want to know the throughput through HAL your methods are fine (a bigger buffer might be useful but that's it). If you want to know the absolute maximum throughput you should use DMA and direct peripheral access (or CMSIS).

Comment: @domen, the datasheet is one thing but it gives a theoretical maximum frequency and we want to know the results in real life, and compare the different modes (DMA or not, execute from RAM or from Flash, etc...). It's also a way to understand better the peripheral management. Of course you're right there is a protocol overhead on top of SPI but this is another topic.

Comment: @TarickWelling, I thouht CMSIS was an interface to access the MCU. Is there a link with peripherals like SPI ?

Comment: Protocol overhead and data handling will be *the* slowdown though. You should easily reach near datasheet maximum speeds with a busy loop doing only SPI TX (you have 32 cycles to send out 8-bits of data, should be plenty). DMA becomes useful when CPU is executing something else, which in your test case is not. RAM/FLASH becomes important when you don't have tight loops (there's a tiny cache for FLASH, to reduce wait cycles), again, not very relevant.

Comment: Pardon me I was thinking of the `Standard Peripheral Library` They don't exist for the H7 but a `Low Level` driver does exist (https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkfWWSAZ/standard-peripheral-library-for-the-stm32f7-series-of-processors) It should be found inside a file akin to `stm32h7xx_ll_spi.h`

Comment: Just a comment: there was something stupid in my original procedure. it doesn't take into account systick overrun, which is very likely to happen since it is configured to count 1ms... Of course I had to use a timer more carefully set.